# Express server 'restarting' fix

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to start my local express server by running the command `node --watch index.js` in my terminal. Then for like 5 minutes it keeps telling me `Restarting index.js` and it keeps flickering in the terminal. Sometimes its for 2 minutes, sometimes 5 minutes straight and then finally it says `example app listening on port 300`0 & `connection succesfull`.

This is very annoying to have to wait minutes everytime I start my server. Is there a fix for this?

index.js code:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

require('dotenv').config()

const cors = require('cors'); // Import the cors middleware
//import routes
const users = require('./routes/api/v1/users');

const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_PW);

//check if the connection is established
const db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function() {
    console.log("Connection Successful!");
});

//import the routes
const renovationsRouter = require('./routes/api/v1/renovations');
const promotorsRouter = require('./routes/api/v1/promotors');

//json body parser
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors()); // Use the cors middleware
app.use('/api/v1/users', users);
app.use('/api/v1/renovations', renovationsRouter);
app.use('/api/v1/promotors', promotorsRouter);

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`)
});
```

Answer (score -1):

watch isn't native to node.js i'd suggest you use nodemon instead

```
npm install nodemon

npx nodemon index.js
```

Comment: I thought it was since v18?